# How to make this chart wider/ enable scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

As you can see, the scrolling is enabled, but when I run the code bellow,it displays the scrollbar,but it is disabled (faded).The chart is displayng almost edge-to-edge on the screen and it is readable if I represent only a few date intervals, but it gets very cramped and unreadable when I put over...15 date intervals for example, and you almost can't even see some smaller ploted intervals, only if you zoom. I want the chart to be wider by default, so I can clearly see all the intervals and can scroll it. The scroll bar is also faded out even when I zoom the chart. I see on all scrollbar examples on highcharts website, the chart scrollbar works and data is ploted on a wide space, but on mine it autofits it all the time and I don't have the scrollbar, please help!

// EDIT: maybe something to do with min,max? but when I try to set any min value it gives me timeline from 1970 to 2020 :/

## [jsfiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/VenomXLR/u3eWz/)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'columnrange',
                    inverted: true,
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Production status'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ["Status"]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Interval'
                    }
                   // tickPixelInterval: 3600*1000
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    columnrange: {
                        grouping: false
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.x + ' - ' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %H:%M', this.point.low) +
                        ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %H:%M', this.point.high) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%M minutes',this.point.high-this.point.low) + '<br/';
                    }
                },
                series: []
            };

            // Load the data from the XML file 
            $.get('Chart_data.xml', function (xml) {

                // Split the lines
                var $xml = $(xml);

                // push series
                $xml.find('series').each(function (i, series) {

                    var seriesOptions = {
                        name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                        data: []
                    };

                    // push data points
                    $(series).find('date').each(function (i, value) {
                        var seriesData = {
                            x: 0,
                            low: Date.parse($(value).find('low').text()+" UTC"),
                            high: Date.parse($(value).find('high').text()+" UTC")
                        };
                        seriesOptions.data.push(seriesData);
                    });

                    // add it to the options
                    options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                });
                
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="container" style="">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

XML Data example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chart>
  <series>
    <name>ChangeOver</name>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 5:25:06 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 5:33:41 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 10:30:02 AM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 11:26:01 AM</high>
    </date>
  </series>
  <series>
    <name>BreakDown</name>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 3:00:23 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 3:02:22 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 5:11:39 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 5:17:51 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 10:23:16 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 10:33:13 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 10:21:18 AM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 10:30:02 AM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 11:54:58 AM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 1:46:06 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 2:33:30 PM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 2:33:45 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 2:33:45 PM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 2:33:52 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 2:33:52 PM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 2:48:39 PM</high>
    </date>
  </series>
  <series>
    <name>Production</name>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 3:02:22 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 5:11:39 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 5:17:51 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 5:25:06 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 5:33:41 PM</low>
      <high>7/30/2014 10:23:16 PM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/30/2014 10:33:13 PM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 10:21:18 AM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 11:26:01 AM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 11:54:58 AM</high>
    </date>
    <date>
      <low>7/31/2014 1:46:06 PM</low>
      <high>7/31/2014 2:33:30 PM</high>
    </date>
  </series>
  <series>
    <name>TrialRun</name>
  </series>
</chart>
```

Output:

[image: chart]

There are actualy more lines than you can see but are so cramped that they can't be noticed like this. And the scrollbar is faded!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle and image of chart how it look initially

Comment: How your parsed data looks like ?

Comment: @loganSarav check post again! edited

Comment: try setting interval values using `tickInterval` for y axis

Comment: @loganSarav please read the code carefuly, it is already there comented, which means it didn't work. (both tickInterval and tickPixelInterval) // updated the post with jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to set min/max values on the yAxis (in inverted charts, axis are flipped).

Comment: maybe you could edit the JSFiddle I provided to show me this?, because I already modified that and it gives me an randomn interval there and no data ploted and no scroll ( tried for example 3600*100 and 3600*100000)

Comment: You need to set min value as Date and max value as date, by Date.UTC() which you have in your data.

Comment: I edited it and set a start and end date in UTC, now it displays a "zoomed" interval but NO scrollbar (it is still faded), as you could've seen yourself if you edited the jsfiddle solution before posting. I'm starting to think Highcharts is kinda bugged.